# Is there a way to get data out of Open Graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I was wondering if facebooks open graph allows you to somehow get the data out of it. For example if you need to find all the movies people have marked up using facebooks open graph is there anyway you can get that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to get permission from the individual users though.  A good source for the data available Facebook OG API is the Open Graph Explorer:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

You may need to register as a Facebook Developer first ( free ).

Comment: perhaps I should rephrase: is there a open access repository where you can get all the pages with open graph mark up in them? Or do I need to crawl the Web myself

Comment: You will not be able to scrape, FB has a good process to detect and block automated scraping...  The most open approach would be to access via the FB Open Graph API.